# ColumnTransformer- Series is ambiguous error

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am trying to create a Pipeline but am getting error

Any suggestions? My both input columns are categorical and output is also category.

Code

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

target = dataframe.final
features = dataframe[['A', 'B']].copy()
X_train1, X_test1, y_train1, y_test1 = train_test_split(features, target,test_size=0.2, 
random_state=42)
numerical_features = features.dtypes == 'float'
categorical_features = ~numerical_features

preprocess = make_column_transformer(
(numerical_features, make_pipeline(SimpleImputer(), StandardScaler())),
(categorical_features, OneHotEncoder()))
model = make_pipeline(
                      preprocess,
                      LogisticRegression())
model.fit(X_train1, y_train1)
```

Error:

```
        ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-53-e1960c314217> in <module>
         14     preprocess,
         15     LogisticRegression())
    ---> 16 model.fit(X_train1, y_train1)
         17 print("logistic regression score: %f" % model.score(X_test1, y_test1))

    ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Problem seems to be due to the logical operations. Did you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look.

Comment: Your pipeline seems confusing. Just try to split it into different lines instead of making it at one row.